# How to include a calender in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I need to include a calender in my asp.net application. Is there any built in methods? I'd appreciate a bit of code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax control toolkit has calender.

> Calendar is an ASP.NET AJAX extender that can be attached to any
>   ASP.NET TextBox control. It provides client-side date-picking
>   functionality with customizable date format and UI in a popup control.

Check it out from http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```

Comment: @Ebenezar_Gislen_Softwares You are quite welcome..

Answer (score 2):

There is a calendar control in the toolbox of visual studio already.check how to customize it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/229445/Customizing-the-ASP-NET-Calendar-Control

If you need another calendars here are some:

Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/calendar.aspx

Ajax calendar: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp.net ajax toolkit for it, you can find it [**here**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar.ashx). You an see the live demo of ajax control kit calender [**here**](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
    TargetControlID="Date1"
    CssClass="ClassName"
    Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
    PopupButtonID="Image1" />
```